# I want to send one primary key to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to send primary key to firebase from android phone so I can recognize who send me the data. So basically I'm making an application that will send image to server. I want to check who send me something. So I will need one primary key. Can any one help me out with this? Like how can I send something unique to firebase server?

```
public  void SignUP(View v){

         EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRegistrationName);
         EditText contact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRegistrationContact);
         EditText city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRegistrationCity);
         EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRegistrationEmail);
         EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRegistrationPassword);

         String userName = name.getText().toString();
         String userContact = contact.getText().toString();
         String userCity = city.getText().toString();
         String userEmail = email.getText().toString();
         String userPassword = pass.getText().toString();

         if(isOnline() == true){
             FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
             DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users").push();


             DatabaseReference nam = myRef.child("Name");
             nam.setValue(userName);

             DatabaseReference contac = myRef.child("Contact");
             contac.setValue(userContact);

             DatabaseReference cit = myRef.child("City");
             cit.setValue(userCity);

             DatabaseReference emai = myRef.child("Email");
             emai.setValue(userEmail);

             DatabaseReference passwor = myRef.child("Password");
             passwor.setValue(userPassword);

         }
         else{
              bal.addUser(new UserBean(0,userName,userContact,userCity,userEmail,userPassword));
              Toast.makeText(this, "Data Save in DB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

Comment: FIrebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrent().getUid()

Comment: what happens inside addUser()?

Comment: Actually if internet not connected then save in db , then when it connected to server  then send all db data to server something like this thats why i made this

Comment: I have not use firebaseAuth bro

Comment: you must use FirebaseAuth, because what you are doing is very insecure. and don't allow auth w/o internet connection

Comment: I have no problem in using FirebaseAuth but the problem is i want to save other data too :|

Comment: well , look 
I want to work something like
First user install application then register ... then one time signin to app 
once login then he can capture the image or video then it will send to server 
if connction not avble then save in db then when ever gets connection it wil send to server  , same thing for registration
if i use auth then i must have internet when user need to login .. u got my point ?

Comment: so i would have liked that you put some more effort in your punction so now your text is pretty hard to read so it might help others better to help you

Comment: After reading the comments, it appears you may be trying to do too much. Many of the functionality you want to create already exists in Firebase. For example, you can enable offline mode persistence with a line of code. Online/Offline syncing is also automated. I would urge you to review all the different header files of the SDK. Most have detailed comments that explain what's already available. In the code example, I provide an answer, if it was helpful please consider providing feedback.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Given that you want to get the user's autogenerated ID you can simply import the FirebaseAuth and with a few lines of code have the unique id for each user. There is no need to worry about explicity sending that to the server as data is automatically synchronized. You can simply use the user-id whenever you need it in your code as you build out your JSON tree. If you want to add it to your data then that is also an easy process that you are already using for other data points. Most of what you mention in comments are already functional within the SDK. So there is no need to reinvent those features from scratch.

The code below is used to enable Auth within your activity.

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
// ...
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
EmailPasswordActivity.java
```

This simple example from the docs show how to authenticate someone using an email and password...

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

// ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
EmailPasswordActivity.java

mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // ...
            }
        });
EmailPasswordActivity.java
```

This sample code shows how to authenticate users anonymously witho requiring any password.

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

// ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
AnonymousAuthActivity.java

mAuth.signInAnonymously()
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // ...
            }
        });
AnonymousAuthActivity.java
```

([FirebaseAuth Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/))

Enabling offline data synchronization:
([Data offline info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities))

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

If you want to force a particular branch of the data tree to be stored locally you can also make a referece to that location and call the keepSynced function passing true. The comments in the header indicate:

> /**
>        * By calling `keepSynced:YES` on a location, the data for that location will automatically be downloaded and
>        * kept in sync, even when no listeners are attached for that location. Additionally, while a location is kept
>        * synced, it will not be evicted from the persistent disk cache.
>        *
>        * @param keepSynced Pass YES to keep this location synchronized, pass NO to stop synchronization.
>        */

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I think you may want to checkout the sample code for Android on the [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). Basically, I think the push().getKey() should return the autogenerated id as noted. My take away from this is that the act of posting will generate the key automatically.

```
private void writeNewPost(String userId, String username, String title, String body) {
    // Create new post at /user-posts/$userid/$postid and at
    // /posts/$postid simultaneously
    String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
    Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```